# QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission issue persist even after remove it

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, flutter-android

I have received a mail from play store that "We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission because the declared task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method." and this issue found in 5.2.0(74) version of my app.

I have removed the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES from manifest file and verified in merged manifest to made sure that QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES were completely removed. I have updated the new version of the app (5.2.3(84)) to all the tracks of play store and submitted for a review. new app is rolled out to the production and still I am seeing a waring message from play store as below.

[image]

Permissions of newly submitted app doesn't contain QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES. See the below image [image]

What am i missing why is that i am still seeing the warning message of app being removed?

Comment: Any update on this issue? we are facing same issue in our project.

Comment: They informed us that , warning appears for longer time. I advise you to send a mail to support team and get a confirmation from them that everything is okay in your app

Comment: I have overcome from this issue by removing old apk that which supports QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES  which we submitted in close and internal testing